# In R ggplot, is there a way to create histograms with no filling colors and vertical borders between bars?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Like the histogram shown below:

[image: plot]
<sub>(source: [cern.ch](https://root.cern.ch/root/html534/guides/primer/figures/TH1F_Example.png))</sub>

Comment: Can you provide data please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe with `geom_step`

```
library('ggplot2')

set.seed(1)
x <- unlist(Map(rpois, 20, 4:1 * 5))
qplot(seq_along(x), x, geom = 'step')
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! Though for this particular problem I would like to see a more generic solution (i.e. using the histogram option). The reason is this solution requires getting the bin content for each bin which may not be straightforward.

Comment: @xiaoxiao87 `x <- hist(data)$counts` if you gave some example data, I could attempt a better answer

Comment: Got it. Thanks! This almost solved the problem except the left/right side of the steps is empty.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Answer (score 8):

A less satisfying way, using layering of a black color hitsogram under one with no color with white fill.

```
set.seed(12)
x <- rpois(1000, 30)

bw <- 2
col <- 'black'
ggplot(data.frame(x), aes(x=x)) + 
    geom_histogram(binwidth=bw, color = col, fill=col, size=2) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth=bw, fill='white') +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]